# Bicoin price prediction using spark and scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, linear-regression

I am trying to build a prediction model for Bitcoin price using Apache spark and scala. I have preprocessed the data and built following format:

1. TimeStamp
2. BTC price
3. USD price
4. MaxPrice
5. minPrice
6. numberTrades
7. openPrice
8. ClosePrice
9. avgPrice

I am using Linear Regression to perform perdition.

```
 val scaler = new StandardScaler(withMean = true, withStd = true)
               .fit(parsedData.map(x => x.features))
  val scaledData = parsedData
              .map(x => 
              LabeledPoint(x.label, 
                 scaler.transform(Vectors.dense(x.features.toArray))))


    val splits = scaledData.randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2), seed = 11L)
  val training = splits(0).cache()
  val test = splits(1)


    // Building the model
    val numIterations = 100
    val step = 0.1
     val algorithm = new LinearRegressionWithSGD()
      algorithm.setIntercept(true)
      algorithm.optimizer
      .setNumIterations(numIterations)
      .setStepSize(step)
      .setRegParam(0.001)
      .setUpdater(updater)
```

The predictions I get are not calculated correctly. It gives me very random predictions.

[image]

Can anybody please help me with this? The same dataset works fine when I do the prediction using Azure ML libraries.

Comment: So the problem is that the RMSE is big or what?

Comment: RMSE is 1.3969991919033754E9

Comment: I think this question is more related to Data Science to something about programming

Comment: Yes this is more about data science.

Comment: Tune until you find the right set of parameters. Also if these predictions are representative sample there is no way you'll get RMSE  1.3969991919033754E9.